# Why the excel lookup return NA

Tags: excel

I am using current forumla in excel but it returns NA. May I know any problem on it

LOOKUP(5,{10,7;9,14;8,14;7,14;6,28;5,28;4,28;3,42;2,42;1,42})

Answer (score 2):

On [microsoft's support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324986) on this, it states:

> If lookup_value is smaller than the smallest value in the first row or column (depending on the array dimensions), LOOKUP returns the #N/A error value.

And most importantly:

> Important The values in array must be placed in ascending order. For example, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 or A-Z or FALSE, TRUE. If you do not do so, LOOKUP may not give the correct value. Uppercase and lowercase text are equivalent.

Your first row is: (10,7), and 5 is smaller than 10, so it returns `#N/A`

If you put your values in ascending order, it should work.

Comment: Thanks, and for this case: =LOOKUP("Low",{"Critical",7;"High",14;"Medium",28;"Low",42})   Why it returns 14 but not 42?

Comment: @Chris.  Sorry, something messed up when I tried copy/pasting the 2nd part (and I got side tracked, so didn't notice till now).  You need to sort your lookkup values (in both cases - need to sort the strings too).

Comment: @Chris:  When sorted: `=LOOKUP("Low",{"Critical",7;"High",14;"Low",42;"Medium",28})`, it returns 42.

Comment: @Gerrat: "Your first row is: (10,7), and 5 is smaller than 10, so it returns `#N/A`" This is not really true. `LOOKUP` uses a binary search algorithm. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm So it will at first check (6,28). 6 is greater than 5. Then it will check (9,14). 9 is greater than 5. At last it will check (10,7). 10 is greater than 5. So `#NV`. `=LOOKUP(5,{10,7;9,14;8,14;7,14;5,28;6,28;4,28;3,42;2,42;1,42})` gets 28.

Comment: @Alex. It is completely true.  Read both blocks I quoted from the microsoft support site.  The first one states **explicitly** why it returns `#N/A`.  Also, please read your own link to the binary search algorithm.  It states: `"within an array sorted by key value"`.  His array isn't sorted.
"

Answer (score 1):

My question would be "why are you using `LOOKUP`?" - If you expect an `exact match` then `LOOKUP` isn't the best function, `VLOOKUP` would be better, i.e.

`=VLOOKUP(5,{10,7;9,14;8,14;7,14;6,28;5,28;4,28;3,42;2,42;1,42},2,0)`

That will return 28 and if you change the lookup value to any of the listed values in the lookup range it will still work

If the lookup value is changed to a value that isn't in the list, e.g. `5.5` or `11` you will get `#N/A` error